# React and Firestore Security Rules and Snapshot listener: How to Re-fetch Event Expenses When User Joins and Gains Access?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore database with 'user', 'event', and 'expense' collections. Each 'event' is associated with multiple users as participants, and each 'expense' is linked to a specific event. Initially, when a user navigates to an event they are not a participant of, the expenses associated with that event are hidden, and a "Join" button is displayed. When the user clicks the "Join" button and becomes a participant of the event, the 'event' document is updated to reflect their participation, granting access to the expenses related to that event.

I'm using React and Firestore in my app. The challenge I'm facing is how to re-fetch the 'expenses' query immediately after the user joins the event, as they now have access to view the expenses associated with that event. The 'expense' collection remains unchanged when the user joins an event, and thus the expenses don't automatically become visible without a page refresh.

Here's a simplified version of my React code:

```
function Event() {
  const [user] = useAuthState(fbAuth);
  const { eventId } = useParams();
  const [event, eventLoading] = useGetEvent(eventId as string);

  const eventData = event.data();

  const isUserParticipating = user && eventData?.participantsIds?.includes(user?.uid);

  const [expenses, loading, error] = useGetEventExpenses(eventId as string);

  useEffect(() => {
    // How can I trigger a re-fetch of 'expenses' query when the user joins the event,
    // so that the expenses associated with the event become visible without requiring a page refresh?
  }, [isUserParticipating]);

  // ...jsx
}
```

My Firestore security rules is as follow:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        // Allow write access to the 'event' collection only for authenticated users
        match /event/{eventId} {
            allow read: if true;
            allow write: if request.auth != null;
        }

        match /user/{userId} {
            allow read: if true;
            allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
        }

        // user can only read/write expenses of events he is a participant of
        match /expense/{expenseId} {
            allow create: if request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/event/$(request.resource.data.parentEventId)).data.participantsIds;
            allow delete,read: if request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/event/$(resource.data.parentEventId)).data.participantsIds;
        }

    }
}
```

so, how to update snapshot listener when access to a resource is changed because other document that determines the access this resource was changed?